# Remove whitespace before and after the string dynamically?

Tags: apex, formula, string

I am trying to remove whitespace (dynamically) from an input string:

```
Input:  ' inputString '
Output: 'inputString'

Input:  ' Ravi kumar '
Output: 'Ravi kumar'
```

I want to remove the space before or after the string or both before and after, not in the middle.

I tried the following but it is removing all the spaces including middle.

```
inputString = inputString.replaceAll('\\s+', '');
```

Comment: Have you considered using trim? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use `trim()` [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_trim) of `String` class

> Returns a copy of the string that no longer contains any leading or
>   trailing white space characters.

```
String s1 = '   Hello!   ';
String trimmed = s1.trim();
System.assertEquals('Hello!', trimmed);
```

Answer (score 19):

I like using `normalizeSpace()` instead of `trim()` for such scenarios, as it also handles repeated white space.

> **normalizeSpace()**
>
> Returns the current String with leading, trailing, and repeating white
> space characters removed.

```
String s1 = 
   ' Salesforce \t     force.com ';
String s2 = 
   s1.normalizeSpace();
System.assertEquals(
   'Salesforce force.com', s2);
```