# How to process image URLs in Email Services?

Tags: apex-email-service, regular-expressions

I have written an inbound email service to created records based on custom object. This email service processes replies to the outbound email sent from Salesforce. The outbound email's template and letterhead contains the logos. So when the email service runs it returns the following logos' URLs in the textbody.

> From: "procurement@UXG.com"
>   
>   
>   Sent: Monday, August 27, 2018 9:35 PM To: Jacks, Roger (VISPL)
>    Subject: [EXT] Sandbox: ** Case #: 1114193
>
> [https://domain.cs92.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015q00000007e50&oid=00Dq00000001Kt0]
>
> Hi Team,
>
> This is regarding email body validation.
>
> Thanks & Regards,
>    Roger Jacks
>
> [https://domain.cs92.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015q00000007e4q&oid=00Dq00000001Kt0]
>
> [http://domain.cs92.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?oid=00Dq00000001Kt0&esid=018q0000000vqVR]
>
> ref:_00Dq01Kt0._500q0BJQKJ:ref

How can I remove the image addresses from the `TextBody` on the `Messaging.inboundEmail` object ? I tried following code but my RegEx expression is not working.

```
String RegEx = '\\bmy.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=\\b';

 Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(RegEx);
 Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(email.plainTextBody);
 String replacedBody;

if(myMatcher.find()) {
   replacedBody = email.plainTextBody.replaceAll(RegEx, '');
}
```

I'm struggling to develop a RegEx expression. My !dea is to find those 3 instances of the image URLs. The common string among them is `.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=`

Comment: What code have you written so far, and which bit doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Bennie, could you post the code you use to generate that email? One more thing: be aware that you are including an image loaded in your salesforce org, so it won' be accessible from external sources (e.g. emails). You should upload these images somewhere public.

Comment: @NickCook I have added what I have written so far. It is RegEx which is not working.

Comment: @Alberto Basically, I'm struggling to develop a RegEx expression. My !dea is to find those 3 instances of the image URLs. The common string among them is `.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are trying to find a specific pattern within a block of text, use regular expression. [`String.replaceAll()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) method is perfect for your situation.

```
String emailBody = '[https://domain.cs92.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015q00000007e50&oid=00Dq00000001Kt0] Hi Team, This is regarding email body validation. Thanks & Regards, Roger Jacks [https://domain.cs92.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015q00000007e4q&oid=00Dq00000001Kt0] [http://domain.cs92.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?oid=00Dq00000001Kt0&esid=018q0000000vqVR]';

String regExp = '\\[(https?)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]\\]';
String withoutUrls = emailBody.replaceAll(regExp, '');

System.debug('Email without urls: ' + withoutUrls);
// Result: Hi Team, This is regarding email body validation. Thanks & Regards, Roger Jacks
```

Apex regular expression is based on Java ([source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm)).

For Java you can find a lot of examples and real-time environments that will make creation of regular expression a lot easier.

I've used [RegEx Planet](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyy5n7p4d).

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is definitely working. Is there anyway I can remove the whitespaces as well ?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/178233/46480